# show/hide modalpopupextender inside updatepanel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an asp.net page with ajax updatepanel and a grid. inside the same updatepanel, I have a modalpopupextender. I want to show modalpopupextender on click of the row button of grid.

I have written this  js:

```
function AddRemoveFavorites(regId) {

            Showpopup();
            return false;
        }

        function Hidepopup() {
            $find('ModalPopupExtender1').hide();
        }
        //Function to Show ModalPopUp
        function Showpopup() {
            $find('ModalPopupExtender1').show();
        }
```

and here is markup for update panel, modalpopup and gridview button column.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="ResultUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="SearchLinkButton" EventName="Click" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="SubmitButton" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" CancelControlID="btnCancel"
                    OkControlID="btnOkay" TargetControlID="Button1" PopupControlID="Panel1" PopupDragHandleControlID="PopupHeader"
                    Drag="true" BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG">
                </ajax:ModalPopupExtender>
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" Style="display: none" runat="server">
                    <div class="HellowWorldPopup">
                        <div class="PopupHeader" id="PopupHeader">
                            Header</div>
                        <div class="PopupBody">
                            <p>
                                This is a simple modal dialog</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="Controls">
                            <input id="btnOkay" type="button" value="Done" />
                            <input id="btnCancel" type="button" value="Cancel" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </asp:Panel>
```

and grid column

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridTitleCor2" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridBorderR"
                            ItemStyle-Wrap="false">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="SavedPH" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("IsSaved").ToString() == "1" %>'>
                                    <a href='#' onclick='AddRemoveFavorites(<%# Eval("RegistrantID").ToString() %>); return false;'
                                        title="<%= Resources.UserProfile.C_SerRes_RemoveFavorites %>">
                                        <img id='<%# String.Format("StatusImage_{0}", Eval("RegistrantID").ToString()) %>'
                                            src="/Images/StarYellow.png" />
                                    </a></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="NotSavedPH" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("IsSaved").ToString() == "0" %>'>
                                    <a href='#' onclick='AddRemoveFavorites(<%# Eval("RegistrantID").ToString() %>); return false;'
                                        title="<%= Resources.UserProfile.C_SerRes_AddFavorites %>">
                                        <img id='<%# String.Format("StatusImage_{0}", Eval("RegistrantID").ToString()) %>'
                                            src="/Images/StarGrey.png" />
                                    </a></asp:PlaceHolder>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

but I am getting following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'show' of null
```

Answer (score 2):

I found answer here:

http://www.jonathanjungman.com/blog/post/Hiding-ASPNET-Ajax-Modal-Popup-Dialog-Using-JavaScript.aspx

Hope it will help someone at some time

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have solve the issue.

I think what you are missing is on your ModalPopupExtender is BehaviorID="mpe", then in your javascript you will use $find('mpe').show();